# Cannot open rpm.Skipping

Tags: linux, influxdb

I am trying to install the influxDB ,what I just do is:

```
wget https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb-1.0.2.x86_64.rpm  
yum localinstall influxdb-1.0.2.x86_64.rpm
```

I got an error just like this:

```
Cannot open: influxdb-1.0.2.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.
Nothing to do
```

So how to solve it.

Comment: `influxdb-1.0.2.x86_64.rpm` is a corrupt package package. Size = 833 B. .... One of the archive managers (Engrampa) says: "argument is not an RPM package ___ cpio: premature end of archive". ..... The content is text only : PGP signature ( `$ nano influxdb-1.0.2.x86_64.rpm` ).

Comment: **influxdb-1.8.5-alt1.x86_64.rpm** → Size = 28MB → $ wget http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/distributions/ALTLinux/Sisyphus/x86_64/RPMS.classic/influxdb-1.8.5-alt1.x86_64.rpm ...... Ref. https://pkgs.org/download/influxdb

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by:

```
wget http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/distributions/ALTLinux/Sisyphus/x86_64/RPMS.classic/influxdb-1.8.5-alt1.x86_64.rpm
```

as it shows that `influxdb-1.0.2.x86_64.rpm` is a corrupt so I try to install another version,it is useful.